# Webdriver: how to automate input masked NRIC field?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am finding difficulty in automating input masked field, sendKeys is what I have tried.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{nric}" required data-inputmask="'mask': 'a9999999a'" data-mask style="text-transform: uppercase;">
```

what have i try

```
WebElement nric = driver.findElement(By.name("nric"));

nric.sendKeys("S1234567Z");
```

Expected result:
nric field will be filled

Actual result: nric field is not filled

Comment: Can you share the link to that page?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help anyone facing similar problem as me.

```
JavascriptExecutor nric = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
nric.executeScript("document.getElementById('nric').value = 'S1234567Z';");
```

What i am doing here is injecting JavaScript directly and populate the nric text input's value. If anyone have a better explaination, but all means write in the comment, as i too want to learn